# id isn't saving from a link in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, node-modules

I want to save the id of a ticket from feedback page into DB, how can I do this?

The problem is in this line "const ticketId = 'ticketId';",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

### js code:

```
   const ticketId = 'ticketId';
    let rating =[];
    $(".starrr").each((index)=>{
        rating.push({
                    _id:$(`.star-c-${index}`).attr("id"),
                    value:parseInt($(`.star-c-${index}`).attr("data-rating"))
                })
    });

    const comment = $("#comment-feedback").val();
    const feedbackObj = {
        comment:comment,
        rating:rating
    }
```

### controller:

```
  const feedbackform = async (req, res) => {

  Rating.find({delete: false, school : req.session.currentSchool._id}).exec(function(err, ratings){
    if(err)
    {
      console.log(err)
    }
    else
    {
      console.log(ratings);



      req.flash('success', 'Successfully saved feedback');
      res.render("ticket_feedback",{ratingDetail:ratings, ticketId:req.params.id})
    }
  })

};

  router.get('/feedbackform/:id', feedbackform);
```

### link:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/ticket/feedbackform/59b02734e3008a5a6ebcef50" class="btn btn-primary"> Feedback </a>
```

Comment: No clear what your problem is with that line. Any error messages?

Comment: you know that constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.

Comment: @JeroenHeier the scenario is that user will give the feedback on the ticket opened by him, so at ticket there is feedback button by clicking that button it redirect to feedback page (url shown at feedback page: http://localhost:3000/ticket/feedbackform/59b02734e3008a5a6ebcef50) but now I wants to save it with this same id, the error is paste.ofcode.org/GZhPa35AxLu73sBbKJgT45

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi so what should I do

Comment: @JeroenHeier paste.ofcode.org/GZhPa35AxLu73sBbKJgT45     this is error

Comment: Define it so that it can always get a value ‍`let ticketId = 'ticketId';` or `var ticketId = 'ticketId';` and use it

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi now m using var but data is still not saving, error :   (node:7388) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ticketId" at path "_id",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,i think id saving method is worng  var ticketId = 'ticketId';

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi I get its value in ejs file but now how ca I save it in jq <input type="text" value="<%=ticketId%>" readonly>\

Comment: @JeroenHeier  I get its value in ejs file but now how ca I save it in jq <input type="text" value="<%=ticketId%>" readonly>

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes but same